# Display Search API query execution time in search view

Tags: views, search

I am trying to show the query execution time in a View where I'm using the Search API module to return results from an index in Apache Solr. I am pretty sure that in the past I could print something like:

`Your query returned 234 results in 0.035 milliseconds`

at the top or the bottom of the view, but this may have been a feature of the Search API Pages module (which I can't use since it does not work properly for me).

I have searched the various "things" that you can add in the header and the footer part of the view but there is no replacement pattern for this kind of information.

Am I missing an option somewhere? If this is not possible through the UI, is there maybe a way to retrieve and print this programmatically in the Views' template system?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you even tried to search the code for parts of that string?

Comment: Did you check [devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) module, it shows each query execution time on page load (for user with permissions).

Comment: @Yogesh the OP was asking about the Solr execution time (it's not an SQL query). Also they don't say but they might want it shown to end users - definitely not a job for Devel.

Comment: @Lim it looks like you might need to write some custom code to solve this. What version of Drupal is this, and are you confident with PHP?

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong This is D7. I'm very confident with PHP. I just can't find a way to get that information (what do I alter? is there an API call that I could do to Search API?) so that I can then alter the view and add this information in it

Comment: @LimArctan the data required is in the view after the query has been run. See https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins%21views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aexecute/7.x-3.x So you could write a simple views area handler which prints the data from eg $view->execute_time etc.

Comment: @AlfredArmstrong this seems to calculate the execution time based on how much time it took views to render the page not how much it took solr to retrieve the results.

Comment: True it includes the render time but that is likely to be small compared to the time to run the query. You could always add a pre render hook and inject your own timestamp at that point if you really need the extra accuracy.